# Asp.net core: How to get original path in error page by 404 status code

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

In my asp.net core application, after each error that occurs, the requested address is changed to the site error page address
How can I retrieve the original requested address in the error page?

Startup.cs:

```
public class Startup
{
    private const string ErrorHandlingPath = "/Error";

    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddRazorPages();
    }

    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
    {
        app.UseExceptionHandler(ErrorHandlingPath);

        app.UseStatusCodePagesWithReExecute(ErrorHandlingPath);;

        app.UseRouting();

        app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
        {
            endpoints.MapRazorPages();
        });
    }
}
```

Error.cshtml.cs

```
    public class ErrorModel : PageModel
    {
        public void OnGet()
        {
            var status = HttpContext.Response.StatusCode;//=404
            var originalPath = HttpContext.Request.Path.Value;//=Error
            var feauter = Request.HttpContext.Features.Get<IExceptionHandlerPathFeature>();//=null
            var path = feauter?.Path;//=null
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As far as I know, you could get the orginal path by using below codes:

```
    [ResponseCache(Duration = 0, Location = ResponseCacheLocation.None, NoStore = true)]
    public IActionResult Error()    
    {
        //var re = HttpContext.Request.Path;
        var feauter = Request.HttpContext.Features.Get<IExceptionHandlerPathFeature>();
        var path = feauter.Path;

        return View(new ErrorViewModel { RequestId = Activity.Current?.Id ?? HttpContext.TraceIdentifier });
    }
```

Result:

[image]

### Update

Since you used razor page's statuscode re-execute method, you should use IStatusCodeReExecuteFeature.

More details, you could refer to below codes:

```
    public void OnGet()
    {

        var feauter = Request.HttpContext.Features.Get<IStatusCodeReExecuteFeature>();//=null
        var path = feauter?.OriginalPath;//=null
        RequestId = Activity.Current?.Id ?? HttpContext.TraceIdentifier;
    }
```

[image]

Comment: This is only true for 404, not 500

Comment: This is working with 500 error which is thrown by the controller. If your codes couldn't work well. Please post the codes to reproduce it.

Comment: Sorry for mistake, This is only true for 500, not 404

Comment: It seems you use razor page's `IStatusCodeReExecuteFeature`, you should use IStatusCodeReExecuteFeature instead.